# Laravel with datatables: searching encrypted data

Tags: php, laravel, performance, encryption, datatable

I have encountered a great issue while using Laravel's datatables. I have a model that has 3 values automatically encrypted (using Crypt) by setter/getter.

I am using datatables to render a table by doing so:

```
    return datatables()->of(Patient::query())
        ->addColumn('name_surname', function($row){
            return $row->name.' '.$row->surname;
        })
        ->make(true);
```

There is 3 ways to pass a model to datatable:

1. by query (Patient::query())
2. by collection (Patient::all())
3. by DB facade

The third doesnt decrypt data.
The query is ultrafast but doesnt allow searching through data
Collection allows on everything but it's ultra slow. (5-7 seconds / table draw).
I also tried caching it but it didnt bring any help to this to my suprise

How can I possibly search through encrypted data without causing performance to drop so low?

Btw.
That's the Trait im using for setter encryption and getter decryption

```
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
    if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
        $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
    } return $value;
}

public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
        $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }
    return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> **Update (2019-06-02)**: There's a standalone library that implements this, called [CipherSweet](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com). Additionally, a Laravel adapter [is in the works](https://github.com/paragonie/eloquent-ciphersweet).

This has been answered in a blog post titled (appropriately), [Building Searchable Encrypted Databases with PHP and SQL](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql). You can expand upon its contents by asking yourself the following questions:

1. How sensitive is the data I'm encryptiong?

   - People's lives could be severely affected if it was compromised: Use a KDF for the blind index.
   - Not very: Use HMAC for the blind index.
2. Do we want only exact matches in the SELECT query, or are collisions tolerable provided they aren't too numerous?

   - No collisions ever: Use the full KDF/HMAC output.
   - Collisions OK: Truncate (which saves on storage), use as a Bloom filter.

Once you have these questions answered, you're going to make sure your encryption provides ciphertext integrity (e.g. libsodium's `crypto_secretbox()` with a random nonce per message), and you're going to use HMAC/PBKDF2 with **a different key** to generate a **blind index** of the plaintext to store alongside the ciphertext (i.e. separate column).

Instead of querying for the ciphertext, just rebuild the blind index then decrypt the results. This gives you a fast, reliable search operation while still offering semantically-secure data encryption.